# Scenario based approach to value-at-risk optimization using mixed-integer programming

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, big-m, stochastic-programming, chance-constraints

For a discrete set of scenarios, minimising value at risk can be formulated as a mixed integer linear programming problem. If each scenario has equal probability then this can be written as

\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\gamma\\
&\text{subject to} &(-r^{s}){'}X &\leq \gamma + M\cdot Y_{s} &&\text{$s = 1,\dots,S$} \tag1\\
&&\frac{1}{S}\sum_{s=1}^{S} Y_{s} &\leq \alpha \tag2\\
&&Y_{s} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{$s = 1,\dots,S$} \\                       
&&\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} &= 1
\end{align}

where $\alpha$ is the confidence level say $0.05$,
$M$ is a big constant,
$r$ is the return on assets,
$x_{i}$ is the percentage in asset $i$, and
$S$ is the number of scenarios.

If we assume that scenarios do not have same probabilities then constraint $(1)$ can be formulated as:
$(-r^{s}\cdot P_{s}){'}X \leq \gamma + M\cdot Y_{s}$ where $P_{s}$ is the probability of scenario $s$. But I am struggling with redefining constraint $(2)$.

How can this constraint/problem be formulated if scenarios have different probabilities?

Comment: You shouldn't modify constraint (1). For (2), your probability is already there. You just need to move $\frac{1}{S}$ inside the sum and replace it by $P_s$.

Comment: Your suggestion works. Thank you! I did try this earlier with Open Solver, but it was recognising this constraint as non-linear, though I am certain I set it up correctly (as I was able to solve the case for equal probability). I ended up coding it on another platform where it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about \begin{align}\min&\quad\gamma\\\text{s.t.}&\quad(-r^s)^\top X\leq \gamma + M Y_s \qquad s=1,\ldots,S\\&\quad\sum_{s=1}^SP_sY_s \leq \alpha\\&\quad \sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1\\&\quad Y_s\in\{0,1\}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. This answer is along the lines suggested by @Gabriel Gouvine  In the equal probability case, the RHS of constraint (2) $\alpha\cdot S$ is rounded down to the nearest integer.  Would a similar consideration apply in the case of different probabilities i.e. when multiplying probabilities with the binary variable?

Comment: As far as I can see this is not needed, since the left-hand-side does not necessarily sum to an integer value.